# How to create popup window or activity onclick(FAB) with Edittext and ImageButtons

Tags: android, android-activity, android-edittext, popup, floating-action-button

I need to create such pop up window(as in Todoist app), that after the click on FAB this pop up window have to appear on the button of the screen and after opening the keyboard this popup have to be above it. Please  help me guys.

Comment: show what you have done till now. Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating custom pop-up window. You can check here:
https://android--code.blogspot.in/2016/01/android-popup-window-example.html